# SQL Server stored procedure - Table to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, tags

I created an XML Object from an SQL table but still need to insert a tag and hardcode a value for each of my columns.

Here is my query and result

```
SELECT 
EmployeeName, RequestStatus

FROM K2.SmartBoxData.Akin_LeaveRequest_Header_SMO
WHERE ID =32


FOR XML PATH ('Message')

    <Message>
        <EmployeeName>Developer</EmployeeName>
        <RequestStatus>Line Manager Approval</RequestStatus>
    </Message>
```

Here is my desired result

```
<Message>
  <tag>
     <hardcode> my value </hardcode>
     <EmployeeName>Developer</EmployeeName>
  </tag> 

  <tag>
     <hardcode> my value 2 </hardcode>
     <RequestStatus>Line Manager Approval</RequestStatus>
  </tag>
</Message>
```

Comment: it is SQL server actually

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (not an image) and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Nested elements in  tag: `SELECT 
'value 1' as "tag/hardcode", EmployeeName as "tag/EmployeeName",
'' as "text()",
'value 2' as "tag/hardcode", RequestStatus as "tag/RequestStatus"
FROM K2.SmartBoxData....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `FOR XML` subqueries to do this. Make sure to add `,TYPE` to the nested `FOR XML` otherwise it will try escape it.

Do not specify column names for the subqueries

```sql
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT
      hardcode = ' my value ',
      lrh.EmployeeName
    FOR XML PATH('tag'), TYPE
  ),
  (
    SELECT
      hardcode = ' my value 2 ',
      lrh.RequestStatus
    FOR XML PATH('tag'), TYPE
  )
FROM SmartBoxData.Akin_LeaveRequest_Header_SMO lrh
WHERE ID =32
FOR XML PATH ('Message'), TYPE;
```

Alternatively specify column names, but an empty `PATH`

```sql
SELECT 
  tag = (
    SELECT
      hardcode = ' my value ',
      lrh.EmployeeName
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ),
  tag = (
    SELECT
      hardcode = ' my value 2 ',
      lrh.RequestStatus
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  )
FROM SmartBoxData.Akin_LeaveRequest_Header_SMO lrh
WHERE ID =32
FOR XML PATH ('Message'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95d12da3a01bb74dec7bde6543869468)

Comment: Wooh! Thank Charlie, this solves all my problem, I really appreciate

Comment: An additional question I'd like to ask, is there a way I can throw this result (I mean the xml) into that same table, creating a new column then save it into it

Comment: Sure you can, like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c149de75a53655d904651bd4ba1af9c but I would advise you not to, better to just query it when you need it. Maybe create a `VIEW` with this query

Comment: it was helpful but I kept getting this even after several tweaks    "Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query"

Comment: The `,TYPE` on the outer `FOR XML` is making it into `XML`. Are you trying to insert it into a `nvarchar` column or variable? If so just remove it (but not from the inner subqueries), although I would recommend you use a proper `xml` column. Note by the way that the fiddle that I made has a proper `xml` column, not `nvarchar`

Comment: I just solved the issue using a xml column. but I now get the data stored for other rows, I need it stored for only row 32

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for this, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do or what code and data you have

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks Charlie